# How do I remove duplicates from a list from input? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, input, duplicates

I need help with detecting duplicate values when entering a link twice or thrice in a row. Whenever I try to add the same string from the input box It add like what it was supposed to but I want to stop adding the same string again. The input should prevent me from adding exactly the same string to the list.

- not this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**q07RanslaGM**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**q07RanslaGM**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryw9dHlr7Mw

- but this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**q07RanslaGM**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**ryw9dHlr7Mw**

They should not be the same.

```
--Javascript--
var addurl = function() {
var url = input.value;
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML = url;
song = document.getElementById('songurl');
song.appendChild(li);
document.getElementById("geturl").value = "";
console.log('Url added');
}

--html--

<div class="search">
    <div class="center">
            <input type="text" placeholder="https://www.youtube.com/?" id="geturl">
            <input type="submit" value="Add" id="addlist" name="url">   
        </div>      
    </div>
<div class="container" id=#list>
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <ol class="list-item-group" id="songurl"></ol>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Answer (score 2):

```
input = ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q07RanslaGM",

"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q07RanslaGM",

"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryw9dHlr7Mw"]

output =  Array.from(new Set(input))
```

output will be: Array [ "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q07RanslaGM", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryw9dHlr7Mw" ]

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be to add a list where you keep the urls, check if the new url is in list before creating a new element.

```
--Javascript--
var urlList = []
var addurl = function() {
var url = input.value;
if (urlList.findIndex(u => u === url) < 0) {
  console.log('URL already added')
  return
}
urlList.push(url)
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML = url;
song = document.getElementById('songurl');
song.appendChild(li);
document.getElementById("geturl").value = "";
console.log('Url added');
}
```